# Duplicating Views in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I started an android project giving same name to the layout and fragment layout in android studio. Because I want to avoid generating the fragment layout, [see this tutorial](http://google-android-studio.blogspot.com/2013/10/creating-non-frame-layout-with-android.html)

Now when I create a button in the layout file, and execute the program, it duplicates the views. (Another button appears below that button.)

Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: Can you attach your layout file?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use fragments. This is now the suggested way to create android applications. Can you please post your layout file so we can see

Comment: It was because you were adding same xml in your activity and then in fragment as well. Its not the recommended to do like this.

Comment: @Dreagen: I fixed my problem as I posted below. But can you explain how to use the 2 layout files? Also I noticed that java class extends from ActionBarActivity, not from Activity class.

Comment: Its quite a lengthy subject. Basically your activity should be a container for multiple fragments which you switch between based on what your doing in your app. Look here for more info on fragments http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html It's well worth getting yourself familiar with how fragments work

Answer (score 0):

I just commented out  these lines of code and now it is working.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
```